# Solr select only returning ids

Tags: java, postgresql, search, solr

I am new to Solr I followed some tutorials to set it up. I am using Postgresql. When I run `http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*:*` I get back:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">7</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="q">*:*</str>
    </lst></lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="56" start="0">
      <doc>
        <str name="id">1</str>
      </doc>
      <doc>
        <str name="id">2</str>
      </doc>
      ...
      ...
      <doc>
        <str name="id">10</str>
      </doc>
    </result>
  </response>
```

I expected to get back a list of children with first_name and last_name.

The `requestHandler` in my `solrconfig.xml`:

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
 </lst>
```

The my `data-config.xml`:

```
    <dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
        driver="org.postgresql.Driver" 
        name="ds1" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/some_db" user="db_user" password="hatpants" />
  <document name="kids">
    <entity name="kid" pk="ID" dataSource="ds1" 
            query="select id,first_name,last_name from kid">
        <field column="ID" name="id" indexed="true" />
        <field column="FIRST_NAME" name="first_name" indexed="true" />
        <field column="LAST_NAME" name="last_name" indexed="true" />
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I run the data import: `http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import` I get this:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">4</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="initArgs">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst></lst>
    <str name="command">full-import</str>
    <str name="status">idle</str>
    <str name="importResponse"/>
    <lst name="statusMessages">
      <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
      <str name="Total Rows Fetched">56</str>
      <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
      <str name="Full Dump Started">2014-01-04 04:47:14</str>
      <str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 56 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str>
      <str name="Committed">2014-01-04 04:47:14</str>
      <str name="Optimized">2014-01-04 04:47:14</str>
      <str name="Total Documents Processed">56</str>
      <str name="Time taken ">0:0:0.243</str>
    </lst>
    <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
  </response>
```

It would seem to me like it is able to connect to the db. And I do have a total of 56 records in the db. When I do a specific select it doesn't return any results.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I needed to add those fields to my `schema.xml` file to the fields section.

```
<field name="first_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="last_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

and

```
<copyField source="first_name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="last_name" dest="text"/>
```

Comment: For your use case, the multiValued attribute can be eliminated (multiValued is false by default.) The multiValued attribute basically allows one-to-many relationships in a flat Lucene structure. The only time you would need a multiValued attribute is if your documents needed *more than one* first_name or last_name field per record.